# Javascript element on top of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element within a link, and when the user puts his/her mouse over the element, it has an event bound to it so that a div appears. When the user takes the mouse off, the div disappears. However, since the element is on top of a link, it sometimes behaves erratically as the mouse switches between the element and the link.

Well here's an example on jsfiddle.net:

> http://jsfiddle.net/meltzerj/NqHkP

Of course, it acts fine here but not in my app.

Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: Can you please post a sample code.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a sample of your code at http://jsfiddle.net so we can see the issue live.

Comment: well here's the fiddle, although it acts fine here but not in my app... http://jsfiddle.net/meltzerj/NqHkP/

Comment: The difference between the fiddle and my app is that in my app, hovering over the '?' turns the mouse into the arrow.

Comment: @mu is too short, actually yeah, I think that's exactly what's happening in my case

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest solution is to append the helper inside the initiator. That way, if the overlay comes on top of the hover bit, it won't immidiately dissapear, and then re-appear, and then dissapear etc.

```
$("#feed").hover(function() {
    $(this).append('<div class="help_div"><p>These are the top songs as of now as voted on by all DreamStill members.</p></div><div class="feed_arrow"></div>');
}, function() {
    $(".help_div, .feed_arrow").remove();
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/NqHkP/7/)

Comment: I don't think this works for me. Try it with the arrow: http://jsfiddle.net/meltzerj/NqHkP/11/ which is actually what I have

Comment: Presumably just a problem with the CSS, and the fact that the arrow div wasn't inside the parent div. I'm not entirely sure where you want the arrow to be displayed, but check out http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/NqHkP/13/

Comment: the arrow is meant to point to the question mark, and the base of the arrow should be along the appended div